# Link_to questions index error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models:

- posts
- comments
- questions

Comments belong to posts and questions belong to comments. On my posts index page i am showing all the posts as well as the last comment belonging to each post. My problem comes when trying to link the last comment to the questions index page. 
This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
<%= link_to (post.comments.last.try(:[],:body)), comment_questions_path(@comment) %>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Couldn't find Comment with id=questions
```

Here is my `routes.rb` file:

```
 resources :posts do
   resources :comments 
 end

 resources :comments do
  resources :questions 
 end
```

and the `comment_questions_path` when I run `rake routes`:

```
 comment_questions GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions(.:format)  questions#index
```

The server logs:

```
     Started GET "/comments//questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 20:23:14 -0400
     ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM    "schema_migrations"     
   Processing by CommentsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"questions"}
    Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT    1     [["id", "questions"]]
   Completed 404 Not Found in 66ms
```

Comment: need your app routes file, also run rake routes in console and post the result in your question or some other place like gist or pastie.org

Comment: Ok, posted both. Tell me if you need more from the rake routes.

Comment: so the url that you expect to be after clicking on that link should look like:  localhost:3000/comments/5/questions , right? Also please post the server logs where the request is being sent, need to see what params are being sent to server.

Comment: and what is the url you are being redirected to after clicking on it? is it localhost:3000/comments/questions ?

Comment: The url i am redirected to is localhost:3000/comments//questions but yes i want it to be localhost:3000/comments/5/questions. The server logs are posted above.

Comment: few more things, on what page you are now(url), in what page this link is placed, what url you have before clicking on that link? and how do you load `@post` variable?

Comment: looking at your link I'd say your are on `/posts` page, posts#index, but how do you load the `@comment` variable?

Comment: Yes, the link is on the posts index page (/posts). I'm afraid i'm not sure what you mean about loading the @comment variable.

Comment: you have in your link `@comment`, where do you get it from?  my point is your link would work like this: `<%= link_to (post.comments.last.try(:[],:body)), comment_questions_path(post.comments.last) %> `

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. If you want to make that an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you can load `@comment` variable in `/posts` page, `posts#index` action. You are looping through each `post` so unless you are doing:

`@comment = post.comments.last` for each `post` in your page, your link won't work.

your link need to look like:

```
<%= link_to (post.comments.last.try(:[],:body)), comment_questions_path(post.comments.last) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using routes like that! Your CommentsController will have to respond to requests with a `:post_id` (nested) **and** without a `:post_id`. It really should look more like:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments do
    resources :questions
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there any way i can get mine to work without changing the routes or is changing them all my best bet?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Changing them is your best bet. You'll be thankful later down the road if you have your routes setup properly from the start. It makes things a lot easier